# Keras_tuner TypeError('Inputs to a layer should be tensors... )

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, keras-tuner

I was able to finally get the below code, up to the keras_tuner, I mention this as I'm not exactly sure I'm even working out the class structure correctly. I'm doing all of this so as to try put in my own values for "input_size" and "output_size" for the input and output size of the deep layers.

but then I get the error:

raise TypeError('Inputs to a layer should be tensors. Got: %s' % (x,))
TypeError: Inputs to a layer should be tensors. Got: <keras_tuner.engine.hyperparameters.HyperParameters object at 0x000001650C5DCE50>

I don't know how to fix this and why it would even be an issue as everything before it doesn't throw an error.

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
import keras_tuner
from kerastuner import HyperModel

class CNNHyperModel(HyperModel):
    def call_existing_code(self,units, activation, dropout, lr, layers, optimizer, loss, input_size, output_size):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(units=units, input_dim=input_size, activation=activation))
        for i in range(layers):
            model.add(Dense(units=units, activation=activation))
        if dropout:
            model.add(Dropout(rate=0.25))
        model.add(Dense(output_size, activation=activation))
        # model.add(Dense(10, activation="softmax"))
        model.compile(
            optimizer=optimizer,
            loss=loss,
            metrics=["accuracy"],
        )
        return model

    def build_model(test, input_size, output_size):
        hp = keras_tuner.HyperParameters()
        units = hp.Int("units", min_value=32, max_value=512, step=32)
        activation = hp.Choice("activation", ["relu", "tanh"])
        dropout = hp.Boolean("dropout")
        layers = hp.Int('layers', 2, 6)
        lr = hp.Float("lr", min_value=1e-4, max_value=1e-2, sampling="log")
        loss = hp.Choice("loss", ['sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 'categorical_crossentropy'])
        optimizer = hp.Choice("optimizer", ["adam", "RMSProp"])
        # call existing model-building code with the hyperparameter values.
        model = test.call_existing_code(
            units=units, activation=activation, dropout=dropout, lr=lr, layers=layers, optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, \
            input_size=input_size, output_size=output_size)
        return model

input_size = 11
output_size = 8

Testclass = CNNHyperModel(keras_tuner.HyperParameters())
built_model = Testclass.build_model(input_size, output_size)

tuner = keras_tuner.RandomSearch(
    hypermodel=built_model,
    objective="val_accuracy",
    max_trials=3,
    executions_per_trial=2,
    overwrite=True,
    directory="my_dir",

)

tuner.search_space_summary()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with build_model method, for it to be passed into search algorithm make sure it doesn't accept any other argument rather than hp argument.